# Obtener información de una relación eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una relación de 3 ($datos) a 1 ($fecha). Quiero hacer una tabla donde cada fila sean los tres registros de $datos que están relacionados a cada $fecha, pero no consigo hacerlo. Este es el código que estaba intentando emplear:

INDEX.BLADE.PHP:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'route' => 'objetivos.store']) !!}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
            <th>Objetivo {{$obj->id}}</th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>

    @foreach($fechas as $fecha)
        <tr>
                <td>{{$fecha->fecha}}</td>
            @foreach($fecha->objetivos as $objetivo)
                <td>{{$fecha}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach

    <tr>
        <td>
            {!!Form::date('fecha')!!}
        </td>
        @foreach($objetivos as $obj)
            <td>
                {!!Form::time('tiempo[]')!!}
                {!!Form::hidden('obj_id[]', $obj->id)!!}
                {!!Form::hidden('nFilas[]', $nFilas)!!}
            </td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">{!!Form::submit('Agregar datos de hoy')!!}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    public function index()
{
    $fechas=Fechas::all();
    $objetivos=Objetives::all();               //Esta no tiene importancia
    $datos=objetivosApp::all();
    $nFilas=round($datos->count()/3);         //Esta es la que utilizo para asignar el campo fecha_id
    return view('index', compact('datos', 'objetivos','nFilas','fechas'));
}
```

MODELO FECHAS

```
    public function getTiempo()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\objetivosApp');
}
```

**Al utilizar este código no me devuelve la información que deseo, solo el siguiente cartel:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo acabo de agregar!

Comment: Disculpa, ahí acabo de agregar ambas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder hacer la consulta que deseas considera lo siguiente:

- Declarar en cada modelo la relación deseada

  - El modelo `Fecha` debe tener la relación `hasMany`
  - El modelo `Objetivo` *Considera solo renombrarlo así*, debe tener la relación `belongsTo`
- Así mismo el modelo `Objetivo` se asocia con una tabla que no sigue la convención de nombres de Eloquent, entonces deberás declarar una propìedad para su nombre

Modelo `Fecha`:

```
class Fecha extends Model
{
    public function objetivos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Objetivo::class, 'aqui_declaras_llave_forabea', 'aqui_declaras_llave_primaria');
    }
}
```

Modelo `Objetivo`:

```
class Objetivo extends Model 
{
    protected $table = "objetivos_apps";
    public function fecha()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Fecha::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora la consulta:

- Ya tienes las 2 relaciones declaradas
- Deberás invocar al modelo `Fecha`
- Pedir que *cargue de forma ambiciosa* todas sus relaciones con el modelo `Objetivo`
- Para iterarlo dado que quieres todas las fechas con sus objetivos, entonces requieres 2 ciclos `foreach`

Query:

```
$fechas = Fecha::with('objetivos')->get();
```

En la vista:

```
@foreach($fechas as $fecha)
    ...........................
    @foreach($fecha->objetivos as $objetivo)
        ........................................
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

En tu consulta para determinar que columnas de la relación planeas obtener puedes hacer esto:

```
$data = Fecha::with('objetivos:fechas_id,tempo')->get(['id', 'columna1']);
```

En esta consulta:

- Dentro del método `with` invocamos a la relación así como a la llave foránea y la columna deseada del modelo `Objetivo`
- Dentro del método `get()` pasamos un array con: `id` que sería la llave primaria del modelo `Fecha` y posterior puedes agregar dentro de dicho array todas las columnas de ese modelo que quieras recuperar

Comment: Te agradezco! Pero me lanza el error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'objetivos_apps.fechas_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `objetivos_apps` where `objetivos_apps`.`fechas_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4)) ¿Que puede ser?

Comment: Excelente! Mil gracias, en serio! ¿Como podría hacer para que solo me devuelva el valor del campo "tiempo"? Ya que ahora me devuelve la información de todos los campos

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tiempo' in 'field list' (SQL: select `tiempo` from `fechas`)

Comment: Ahora me muestra esta información en cada td: {"id":1,"fecha":"2020-06-07","created_at":"2020-06-07T00:37:03.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-06-07T00:37:03.000000Z","objetivos":[{"fecha_id":1,"tiempo":"05:36:00"},{"fecha_id":1,"tiempo":"06:37:00"},{"fecha_id":1,"tiempo":"03:37:00"}]} ¿En tu maquina funcionaba bien?Porque quizás se algún otro problema en otro documento mio

Comment: No, solo quería que se mostrara el Tiempo. Osea, el campo tiempo de cada objetivo y fecha correspondiente.

Comment: Exacto, esos salen únicamente en el primer <td>, en la columna tiempo. Ya lo puse por fuera del segundo Foreach con el codigo $fecha->fecha. Actualizo el post para que los puedas ver.

Comment: Ahí subí foto de como se sigue viendo

Comment: Va lo acabo de solucionar por fin, en breves subo fotos de lo que tenia que hacer, mil gracias por toda tu ayuda! Si algún día me encuentro en la capacidad de recompensarte no lo dudaré ni un segundo!